# Does A-frame work on stand alone Oculus/Meta devices?

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

If someone opens the web page in the meta browser (the headsets web browser) will the vr still work?

Comment: Works on my quest 1. Navigate to aframe -> showcase -> vr and it should work